# Button Click Gives Different Errors On Subsequent Launches

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsviewcontroller

I've never seen this response before, where the same action, on different runs of the same app throws different errors.

I have an IBAction for a button (that just logs sender) in an NSViewController subclass that throws the errors upon clicking the button (this is an OSX app). I'm getting these (so far):

```
-[NSArrayM buttonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
-[__NSCFDictionary buttonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
-[__NSCFSet buttonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
-[NSRunLoop buttonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

And, the dreaded EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The only code in this test app is this in the app delegate to instantiate the view controller:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    TestController *controller = [[TestController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

And this IBAction in the view controller subclass:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
}
```

The IBAction which is implemented in the view controller is connected in IB (through File's Owner) to the button which is in its view.

I can't understand how I can get so many different error messages in such a simple program. Could this be a problem with the view controller not being in the responder chain?  If so, why should it throw errors, shouldn't the message just get sent up the chain and then be discarded?

I've tried having the controller's view set the controller as the next responder (with [controller.view setNextResponder:controller];), but that just gives me the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error upon launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this with a pointer from Shane Stanley over at MacScripter (I had made another version in ApplescriptObjC to ask the question over there, but that version worked).  It's a matter of memory management -- too easy to forget about that when using ARC.  The TestController instance was being deallocated before I was sending the IBAction to it.  This explains the variable error messages, because sending a message to a deallocated object can point to anything.  The problem was fixed by declaring a property (as retain) for the TestController instance, controller.